# Implementar Select dependente com AJAX e JQuery no Zend

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, zend

Sou novato em programação e estou montando um pequeno sistema para um controle especifico de arrecadação. Mas preciso preencher alguns campos sem recarregar a página (*AJAX*) e outros quando o `select` for setado, mas estou sem a mínima ideia de como fazer isso.

Estou postando o código abaixo e vou explicar meu objetivo: Preciso fazer o campo "Saldo Anterior" ser preenchido dinamicamente após o `select` "Município" ser setado (pegando o id do município e consultando a tabela movimento para buscar o saldo).

### Model:

```
class Application_Model_Movimento extends Zend_Db_Table {

protected $_name = 'tb_movimento';
protected $_primary = 'id';

public function inserir($table, $array_dados, $return = null) {
    try {
        return $this->getAdapter()->insert($table, $array_dados);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        throw $ex;
    }
}

public function editar($table, $array_dados, $where) {
    try {
        $this->getAdapter()->update($table, $array_dados, $where);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        throw $ex;
    }
}

public function excluir($table, $where) {
    try {
        return $this->getAdapter()->delete($table, $where);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        throw $ex;
    }
}

public function findMovimento($table, $where) {
    $select = $this->fetchRow($this->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false)->from($table)->where($where));
    return $select->toArray();
}

public function buscar($table) {
    $select = $this->fetchAll($this->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false)->from($table));
    return $select->toArray();
}

}
```

### Controller:

```
public function salvarMovimentoAction() {
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();

    $model = new Application_Model_Movimento();
    $util = new Recursos_Util();

    $dados = $this->_getAllParams();
    $id = $dados['id'];
    $where = "id=" . $id;

    //Pegando dados da Tabela Associação
    $resultado_associacao = $model->buscar('tb_associacao');

    //Formatação de Dados para grava no banco
    $id_associacao = $resultado_associacao[0]['id'];
    $valor_bruto_icms = $util->formataNumero($dados['valor_bruto_icms']);
    $valor_saldo_ant = 0;
    $valor_recolher_icms = 0;
    $valor_total = $valor_saldo_ant + $valor_recolher_icms; //Valor da soma total que deve ser recolhida com os lançamentos diários, semanais ou mensais.
    $valor_rec_total = 0; //Valor dos lançamentos acumulados
    $valor_saldo_prox = $valor_total - $valor_rec_total;

    //## Inserindo os Dados ##
    $array_dados = array(
        "id_municipio" => $dados['id_municipio'],
        "data_abertura" => $dados['data_abertura'],
        "data_encerramento" => $dados['data_encerramento'],
        "valor_saldo_ant" => $valor_saldo_ant, //Valor dos saldo de movimentos anteriores que estão pendentes de recolhimento
        "valor_bruto_icms" => $valor_bruto_icms, //Valor do ICMS total do município no período, é digitado pelo usuário
        "valor_recolher_icms" => $valor_recolher_icms,
        "valor_rec_total" => $valor_rec_total,
        "valor_saldo_prox" => $valor_saldo_prox,
        "id_associacao" => $id_associacao
    );

    $table = "tb_movimento";

    if ($id == null) {
        $model->inserir($table, $array_dados);
    } else {
        $model->editar($table, $array_dados, $where);
    }
    return $this->_helper->redirector('index');
}
```

### phtml:

```
<div><b>Movimentação Financeiro da Associação</b></div>
<form id="incluir-municipio" action="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'movimento', 'action' => 'salvar-movimento'), null, true) ?>" method="post" class="form-group" role="form">
<div class="form-group">
    <table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-condensed">
        <tr>
            <td class="col-md-3" style="alignment-adjust: central; alignment-baseline: central; width: 200px;">
                <label for="id_municipio">Município</label>
                <select <?= $this->disabled ?> id="id_municipio" name="id_municipio" class="form-control" value="<?= $this->id_municipio ?>" required="required">
                    <option>Selecione um Município</option>

                    <?php foreach ($this->todos_municipios as $municipios) { ?>

                        <option value="<?php echo $municipios['id'] ?>"><?php echo $municipios['nome']; ?></option>

                    <?php } ?>

                </select>
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-3" style="alignment-adjust: central; alignment-baseline: central; width: 200px;">
                <label for="data_abertura">Data de Abertura do Movimento</label>
                <input id="data_abertura" name="data_abertura" class="form-control calendario" value="<?= $this->codigo ?>" placeholder="Selecione a data de abertura" required="required" type="date" maxlength="10" pattern="[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}$"/>
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-3" style="alignment-adjust: central; alignment-baseline: central; width: 200px;">
                <label for="data_encerramento">Data de Encerramento do Movimento</label>
                <input id="data_encerramento" name="data_encerramento" class="form-control calendario" value="<?= $this->codigo ?>" placeholder="Selecione a data de encerramento" required="required" type="date" maxlength="10" pattern="[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}$"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="table table-responsive">
        <tr>
            <td class="col-md-3" style="alignment-adjust: central; alignment-baseline: central; width: 200px;">
                <label for="valor_saldo_ant">Saldo do Movimento Anterior</label>
                <input disabled id="valor_saldo_ant" name="valor_saldo_ant" class="form-control valor_monetario" value="<?= $this->nome ?>" type="text" placeholder="Digite o Nome do Município" required="required">
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-3" style="alignment-adjust: central; alignment-baseline: central; width: 200px;">
                <label for="valor_bruto_icms">Valor Bruto do ICMS do Município</label>
                <input id="valor_bruto_icms" name="valor_bruto_icms" class="form-control valor_monetario" value="<?= $this->nome ?>" type="text" placeholder="Digite o Nome do Município" required="required">
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-3" style="alignment-adjust: central; alignment-baseline: central; width: 200px;">
                <label for="valor_bruto_icms">Valor do ICMS para Associação</label>
                <input disabled id="valor_bruto_icms" name="valor_bruto_icms" class="form-control valor_monetario" value="<?= $this->nome ?>" type="text" placeholder="Digite o Nome do Município" required="required">
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-3" style="alignment-adjust: central; alignment-baseline: central; width: 200px;">
                <label for="valor_recolher_icms">Valor a ser Recolhido</label>
                <input disabled id="valor_recolher_icms" name="valor_recolher_icms" class="form-control valor_monetario" value="<?= $this->nome ?>" type="text" placeholder="Digite o Nome do Município" required="required">
                <p class="help-block" style="font-size: 10px;"><i>Valor ICMS da Associação + Saldo Movimento Anterior</i></p>
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-3" style="alignment-adjust: central; alignment-baseline: central; width: 200px;">
                <label for="valor_rec_total">Valor Recolhido</label>
                <input disabled id="valor_rec_total" name="valor_rec_total" class="form-control valor_monetario" value="<?= $this->nome ?>" type="text" placeholder="Digite o Nome do Município" required="required">
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-3" style="alignment-adjust: central; alignment-baseline: central; width: 200px;">
                <label for="valor_saldo_prox">Saldo para próximo Movimento</label>
                <input disabled id="valor_saldo_prox" name="valor_saldo_prox" class="form-control valor_monetario" value="<?= $this->nome ?>" type="text" placeholder="Digite o Nome do Município" required="required">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Sei que isso é feito com *JQuery* + *AJAX*, mas não tenho ideia de como fazer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Código Jquery

```
//Chama assim que você altera o select
$( "#id_municipio" ).change(function() {
    //guarda o value do item selecionado do select
    var id_municipio = $(this).val();

    //Requisição ajax passando o id e a chamando a url do seu action no zend    
    $.get( "localdoaction.php", { id_municipio: "id_municipio"} )
    .done(function( data ) {        
        //a variavel data tem os dados que foram retornado do zend

        //popula o campo com os dados vindos do zend
        $("#valor_saldo_ant").val(data.saldo_anterior);     
    });  
});
```

Esse código é para você ter uma ideia, e no seu action você transforma os dados de retorno em um json usando a função do zend Zend_Json.
Da uma olhada na documentação do zend e também do jquery.